# How do I enable breakpoints when debugging a cmake project via WSL in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have created the default cmake template project in Visual Studio 2019 which just contains a single cout in the main function. I then also set up the WSL-Debug build configuration which is unchanged from the default template. I can then run the project in a Windows Subsystem for Linux instance by pressing run.

If I try to set a breakpoint in this program it simply says `The breakpoint will not be hit. Module containing this breakpoint has not yet loaded or the breakpoint address could not be obtained.` when I run it.

How do I get them to work properly?

Comment: Did you follow the instructions presented [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/c-with-visual-studio-2019-and-windows-subsystem-for-linux-wsl/)?

Comment: @squareskittles Yes I did, that is the exact page I used for the setup.